# Conflict of path variables in Ubuntu (Android_home)

Tags: android, linux, path, monodevelop

when I type whereis adb, it says this

`/usr/bin/adb /usr/share/man/man1/adb.1.gz`

but when i type echo $ANDROID_HOME, it says this

`usr/lib/android-sdk/`

... how to resolve this conflict?  I believe it started after I installed MonoDevelop

because I have to type sudo adb kill-server and sudo adb start-server to get it to recognize certain devices, and it sometimes says adb server is out of date starting a new one and none of these are good signs.  Thanks.

Comment: Is `/usr/bin/adb` a symlink into `usr/lib/android-sdk/`? Otherwise you have multiple versions of installed and that makes sense based upon adb error message. MonoDevelop does not install `adb`, maybe a 3rd-party extension or some other package you install. Delete the older `adb` or symlink it into your android sdk location.

Comment: you're right it's probably android-studio that caused the conflict.  somehow i had version 39 installed in the lib folder, but i deleted that now i'm down to v32 in the bin folder without fixing the path issue.  I deleted android-studio after i found out i don't need it, but that didn't fix everything

Does the bin folder come with uiautomator and everything?  Because i'll need to be running Appium on here.

I also found out the ????? serial and unauthorized bit can be solved by going kill-server and sudo start-server.  some devices linux just needs sudo rights to access

Comment: I got it working, only by deleting the instance in /usr/bin/.  Appium for some reason looks in usr/lib/ but linux by default wants it in /bin.  I can't type adb into terminal, even though i added it to my environment variables.  But as my program and appium both point to /lib/ folder which has version 39, it is solved.. sort of..